# CakePHP 3 DefaultPasswordHasher

Tags: cakephp, hash, cakephp-3.0

I am working on creating an authentication form that has a password and password_again field in it. So I can check to make sure they match, I am using the beforeSave() function of my UsersTable to take care of the hashing. As a test, I have just set it to show me the password_again, its hashed result and then die.

```
    public function beforeSave($event, $entity){
        debug($entity->password_again);
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        $entity->password_again = $hasher->hash($entity->password_again);
        debug($entity->password_again);
        die();
    }
```

I am curious as to why the hash keeps changing every time I reload the results. I would have expected the hash to stay the same each time I reloaded it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So it turns out that you should not hash both passwords and then try to compare them. Instead, the DefaultPasswordHasher->check(password_again, password_hash) will verify if the passwords match for you.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Exactly, it should use this method for it. That is also how CakePHP2.x implementations of this PHP5.5 code do it like in their [comparison methods](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/PasswordableBehavior.php#L419): `...->check($value, $dbValue)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `DefaultPasswordHasher` uses PHP's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which by default uses blowfish algorithm with a different salt each time, resulting in different hash on every invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function checkPassword($passedPassword, $actualPassword) {
    if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($passedPassword, $actualPassword)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further?